# Python p-value from t-statistic

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have some t-values and degrees of freedom and want to find the p-values from them (it's two-tailed).  In the real world I would use a t-test table in the back of a Statistics textbook; how do I do the equivalent in Python?

e.g.

`t-lookup(5, 7) = 0.00245` or something like that.

I know in SciPy if I had arrays I could do `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`, but I don't.  I just have t-statistics and degrees of freedom.

Comment: Presumably stats tables exist for convenience instead of having to calculating those values from an equation. Given this is a computer program, why not use that equation directly instead?

Comment: It's quite complicated.  I would hope there was some method somewhere in some library that could do it for me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html

> As an exercise, we can calculate our ttest also directly without using
>   the provided function, which should give us the same answer, and so it
>   does:

```
tt = (sm-m)/np.sqrt(sv/float(n))  # t-statistic for mean
pval = stats.t.sf(np.abs(tt), n-1)*2  # two-sided pvalue = Prob(abs(t)>tt)
print 't-statistic = %6.3f pvalue = %6.4f' % (tt, pval)
t-statistic =  0.391 pvalue = 0.6955
```

Comment: Why do they call it (stats.t.sf) a survival function?  Is it actually the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function

Comment: What if it were a one-sided test?

Comment: Follow-up to the accepted answer: The p-value of one-sided t-test is the p-value of the two-sided t-test divided by 2:
```
pval_one_sided = stats.t.sf(np.abs(tt), n-1)
```

Comment: The correct link to the tutorial changed. It is now:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html

Answer (score 8):

We can compute using the `t.cdf()` function too:

```
from scipy.stats import t
t_stat = 2.25
dof = 15
# p-value for 2-sided test
2*(1 - t.cdf(abs(t_stat), dof))
# 0.03988800677091664
2*(t.cdf(-abs(t_stat), dof))
# 0.03988800677091648
```

The below figure shows how the critical region for 5% level of significance looks like for a 2-sided t-test. For the above example, we can see that the null hypothesis can be rejected.

[image]