# Finding Two-Tailed P Value from t-distribution and Degrees of Freedom in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, p-value

How do I determine the P Value of a t-distrobution with n degrees of freedom.

Research on this subject points me to this stack exchange answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604216

I assume np.abs(tt) is the T-value, but how do i work in degrees of freedom, is that the n-1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `n-1` is the degrees of freedom in that example.

Given a t-value and a degrees of freedom, you can use the "survival function" `sf` of [`scipy.stats.t`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html) (aka the complementary CDF) to compute the one-sided p-value.  The first argument is the T value, and the second is the degrees of freedom.

For example, the first entry of [the table on this page](http://www.gla.ac.uk/sums/users/jdbmcdonald/PrePost_TTest/pandt2.html) says that for 1 degree of freedom, the critical T value for p=0.1 is 3.078.  Here's how you can verify that with `t.sf`:

```
In [7]: from scipy.stats import t

In [8]: t.sf(3.078, 1)
Out[8]: 0.09999038172554342   # Approximately 0.1, as expected.
```

For the two-sided p-value, just double the one-sided p-value.