# Excel's TDIST in SciPy

Tags: excel-formula, scipy, statistics

I have an excel sheet which does a one sample 2 tailed t-test to calculate statistical significance.

The last step of the calculation uses the excel TDIST formula with these arguments:

1. t-stat
2. degree of freedom
3. tails (called with 2 for a 2 tailed test)

What is the exact SciPy equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from scipy import stats

stats.t.sf(t_statistic, df=degrees_of_freedom) * 2
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604216/4822174) has more information.